# A question about limits.

Tags: limits

Here is a question about limits,and I'm trying to solve it.
I'll be grateful if you can provide any hints. Thanks.

Given that  $$\lim_{x\to -1^+}f(x)=1, \lim_{x\to -1^-}f(x)=2, \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=3, \lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=4,$$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=5, \lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=6, \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=7, \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=8$$

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x^3-x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x^2-x^4).$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The task is to find out whether $x^3-x$ and $x^2 - x^4$ approach $0$ from above or below if $x$ approaches $0$ from above. Try plotting the two functions to gain an intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that for $0<x<1$ and $m>n>0$ we have $x^m<x^n$ and therefore

- $x\to 0^+ \implies (x^3-x)\to0^-$ that is with negative values
- $x\to 0^+ \implies (x^2-x^4)\to 0^+$ that is with positive values